# browser_action behaviour on click. It reloads my popup.html and deletes sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want the browser_action to do like show and hide the popup.html. Not reloading.
My Chrome Extension does capture user interaction and store in sessionStorage for further steps. But as soon as I click on the browser_action button, it just reloads popup.html and everything is lost.

Please help

My manifest.json file:

```
{
"name": "...",
"version": "0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,

"permissions": [ "tabs", "storage"],
"background_page" : "background.html", 
"background": {

"persistent": false,
"scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"description": "---",
"icons": {
"128": "icon.png"
},

"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",

"browser_action": {

"default_popup": "popup.html",
"default_icon": "icon.png"
  }

}
```

popup.html:

```
    <script src="background.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form method="get" name="form">
<center>
<input type="button" name="bt" value="Record" id="b1"></input><br><br>

Status: <br><input type="text" name="status" value="Not recording" align="middle" id="status1" disabled></input>
</form>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

background.js:

```
.
..function record(){
do stuff
sessionStorage.setItem(result, id);
}
...functions
....functions 

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener("click",record);

});
```

Comment: Please, post your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how browserActions are expected to work and you can not change them to toggle on click.

> Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated. [¹](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage)

If you want storage to be more persistent use `localStorage` instead. It has the same interface as `sessionStorage` but won't get reset in new tabs/popups.